# sending keypress signal

Tags: c#, console, keypress, signals

I m developing a program and i have to send a keypress signal to the serial port bu console application does not allow me to use System.Windows.Forms name space. In this namespace there is a SendKeys method but i cannot use it. Can anyone suggest something to me or  how can i use System.Windows namespace in my console application?

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Send a keypress signal to the serial port? What do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense to send a keypress to the serial port. The `SendKeys` method simulates the user pressing keys on their keyboard, but that doesn't go to the serial port. Are you trying to control a device attached to the serial port?

Comment: @spender: I'm guessing OP is asking how to send a character to the serial port by simulating a key press, not from the actual keyboard.

Comment: @MPelletier: What key press would (s)he be simulating? I'm not familiar with a serial port that accepts keyboard input. And `SendKeys` certainly wouldn't work this way, which the question seems to indicate is the ideal solution, beyond the fact it doesn't work in a console app.

Comment: @CodyGray: I was just trying to interpret what OP was getting to, admittedly with difficulty. I took it as: "I want to send characters to the serial port." I think there was a language barrier at play here, and it's not C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is what you are after.